# How can I query the children by filtering the parents field in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

Let's say my parent collection (Category) has a field called locale.

This category may have subcategories and products, and products can be in each subcategory.

What I need is, query the all products, whose parent's locale is "en_US".

What is the query or script to list it?

Comment: Did anything here answer your question? If not can you provide more information so people can properly answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not likely going to be the answer you need as your data is probably structured differently. But consider the following document:

```
 {
      "product_id": "ABCD",
      "name": "A better widget for everyone"
      "categories": [
         {
             "name": "toys",
             "locale": "en_US",
         },
         {
             "name": "games",
             "locale": "en_AU"
         }
      ]

 }
```

So if your data **was** structured like that you could do:

```
 db.products.find({ "category.locale": "en_US" })
```

And that **would** get you all the product results in a single step.

So that *may not be* what you have right now, but this serves as an example of how, by **loosing** a little fear over *de-normalization* of data like this, you reap the benefits.

So the general case here is if your **"category"** information *rarely* changes or that you can otherwise *live with* hunting down and updating within the "Product" documents, then this is where an embedded schema **really** helps you.

Then again. We don't know much about your data from the way you have phrased your question. To date that is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming a lot about your schema, but in the shell you could do something like:

```
var parentCategories = db.category.find({locale: 'en_US'});
var categories = [];
parentCategories.forEach(function(category){
    categories = categories.concat(db.category.find({parent_id: category._id}));
});
```